# Bash: Syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: shell, variable, source, special-characters

I have created a shell script that uses information stored in a config file. The issue I am facing is when I try to pass certain values stored in the config file, for use by the shell script, I get a syntax error.

For example:

**config.conf**

```
host=localhost
user=user
password=GhR6R3#h]dSq+C74)Jz9CDF6a7^&L[4= (not my real password)
db_name=database
```

**script.sh**

```
# Load config file TODO: make this more secure
source /path/to/config.conf

# MySQL database dump
mysqldump --lock-tables -h $host -u $user -p $password $db_name > dbbackup_`date +"%Y%m%d"`.bak
```

This is what happens when I attempt to run the script:

```
$ bash script.sh
Syntax error near unexpected token `)'
`password=GhR6R3#h]dSq+C74)Jz9CDF6a7^&L[4='
```

The issue seems to be related to certain characters used in my randomly generated password. I have tried wrapping `$password` in quotes and when that didn't work I did the same with the actual password stored in the config file, but again I had no success.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: try using \ before the special characters in your password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes as much as you can.

config.conf should be like

```
host="localhost"
user="user"
password="GhR6R3#h]dSq+C74)Jz9CDF6a7^&L[4="
db_name="database"
```

And than your command:

```
mysqldump --lock-tables -h "${host}" -u "${user}" -p"${password}" "${db_name}" > dbbackup_`date +"%Y%m%d"`.bak
```

and you should be safe.

Comment: This still caused a slight issue: `Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'database'@'localhost' to database 'GhR6R3#h]dSq+C74)Jz9CDF6a7^&L[4=' when selecting the database`. I seem to have now solved the problem by using your solution together with using the long form `--password="$password"`

Comment: I edited the answer to be precise - there shouldn't be a space between `-p` and password string. Or to use --password as you do.